# Muitos logs com a mensagem "setTypeface with style : 0"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, log, textview

[image: Log cat]Estou fazendo um `app` no `android studio`, e depois de passar algumas `activities` a tela fica preta e o ultimo registro do `log cat` é essa mensagem. Já olhei as outras perguntas sobre isso mas nenhum resolveu meu problema. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece quando vc faz uma chamada 
ao método 
`view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,0)` ou `view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.NORMAL)`

Troque para: `view.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT) (view being a TextView)`

Comment: Essa é a questão, eu não estava fazendo nenhuma chamada a esse método. Mesmo assim tentei usar essa solução, mas a mesma coisa continua acontecendo.